# wrong dictionary updated with switcher in python

Tags: python, switch-statement

I am surprised why __handicapped_slots dictionary is getting updated while i try to update only
__compact_spots and __large_spots using add_parking_spot() method.
Am i doing wrong with switcher feature in python?

```
from enum import Enum


class ParkingSpotType(Enum):
    HANDICAPPED, COMPACT, LARGE, MOTORBIKE, ELECTRIC = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5


class ParkingFloor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
        self.__handicapped_spots = {}
        self.__compact_spots = {}
        self.__large_spots = {}
        self.__motorbike_spots = {}
        self.__electric_spots = {}

    def add_parking_spot(self, type, slot_no):
        switcher = {
            ParkingSpotType.HANDICAPPED: self.__handicapped_spots.update({type: slot_no}),
            ParkingSpotType.COMPACT: self.__compact_spots.update({type: slot_no}),
            ParkingSpotType.LARGE: self.__large_spots.update({type: slot_no}),
            ParkingSpotType.MOTORBIKE: self.__motorbike_spots.update({type: slot_no}),
            ParkingSpotType.ELECTRIC: self.__electric_spots.update({type: slot_no}),
        }
        i = switcher.get(type, 'Wrong parking spot type')
        print(self.__handicapped_spots)
        return i

    def show_parking_spot(self):
        print("Motor bike Parking Spot: ", self.__motorbike_spots.keys())


obj = ParkingFloor('ram')
obj.add_parking_spot(ParkingSpotType.COMPACT, 'C1')
obj.add_parking_spot(ParkingSpotType.LARGE, 'L1')
```

output:
{<ParkingSpotType.COMPACT: 2>: 'C1'}
{<ParkingSpotType.COMPACT: 2>: 'C1', <ParkingSpotType.LARGE: 3>: 'L1'}

Comment: The update() function will be invoked for each and every dictionary every time you call add_parking_spot. Also, you've overridden *type* which is ill-advised

Comment: @DarKnight why it is invoked for each and every dictionary ? it should be invoked for matching type only and after that break the switcher.  how can i fix that?

Comment: The clue here is that your *switcher* dictionary is constructed every time *add_parking_spot* is invoked. You need a complete re-design and, ideally, utilising code that doesn't override *type*

Comment: i changed type ---> mytype but no effect. what type of redesign is needed here?   for testing purpose i have removed dict and put string against each type....and i see code runs only for selected type  ParkingSpotType.HANDICAPPED: 'handicapped'  prints handicapped only when i select type ParkingSpotType.HANDICAPPED..........so why it is not working in dict case?

Comment: The **complete** type of redesign I'm afraid

Comment: does it mean, i should not use switcher and rely on other ways?

Comment: That is a fair assessment of the situation

Comment: then what is the use of switcher if it can not update a dict based on case selection?

Comment: There's nothing special about *switcher* - it's just a dictionary. Its mere existence (as used in your code) serves only to update 5 dictionaries every time you invoke *add_parking_spot* which is almost certainly not what you want